# Stop Spring Boot on thread error

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I have this configuration using Spring Boot:

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor a() {
  return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
}

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner b() {
  return (String... args) -> {
    RunnableTask task = SomeRunnableTask();
    a().execute(task);
  };
}
```

When that thread stops (for any reason) I want to shut down the Spring Boot application.

The thread is a long running process connecting to a database, webservice, socket... So it's quite likely that at some point it'll fail.

What's the right way of shutting down Spring Boot when a thread stops? Should I not be using `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` from Spring?

Thanks!

Comment: So what have you tried to exit the app? Has `System.exit(1)` not worked for you?

Comment: `System.exit(1)` I tried it, and it works, but I'd definitely prefer to shut down the application in a graceful way, calling the Spring Boot `close()` method, to make sure everything is cleaned up. Does that not make more sense than a simple and "brutal" `System.exit(1)`?

Comment: @Strelok anyway I'm not a developer so if you think I should just exit the system like that, I'm happy to. I was expecting Spring Boot to have some mechanism of telling me when a thread is dead, so I can act accordingly.

Comment: Also, what if that thread was running third-party code? What to do there then? You would not be able to `System.exit(1)`...

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot has a [`ShutdownEndpoint`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/ShutdownEndpoint.java) which

> Allows the application to be gracefully shutdown (not enabled by default).

You have to take a look on it:

```java
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500L); // For the response to be sent back to the requester
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        ShutdownEndpoint.this.context.close();  // The ConfigurableApplicationContext 
    }
});
thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
thread.start();
```